# Merge & center every 2 cells in a range in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, loops, merge

I am trying to figure out how to merge every 2 cells in a column. I feel like I am overthinking it though. My if then statement isn't necessary I was just playing around.  Here is the code:

```
Dim RgToMerge As String

   For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).row
   RgToMerge = ""
   If Cells(i, 3) = "" Then
   RgToMerge = "$C$" & i & ":$C$" & i + 1
   With range(RgToMerge)
       .Merge
       .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
       .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter

   End With
   Else
   End If
Next I
End sub
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "every 2 cells." How is this different than the last question you asked?

Comment: I want to be able to merge every 2 cell rows in column C so C3:C4, C5:C6, C7:C8, etc. without having to type all of those out

Comment: Try adding `Step 2` to the end of your `For...` and start it with `For i = 3 ...`

Answer (score 2):

Take out the `if-statement` and make these subtle changes

```
Dim RgToMerge As Range


For i = 3 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row Step 2

    Set RgToMerge = Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i + 1, 3))
    With RgToMerge
        .Merge
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With

Next i
```

Step 2 will loop through every other row. Step 3 would do every third row, etc.

Comment: It worked when I tested it. Can you give me a sample of your input?

Comment: okay I see it works when I input a value in there..since I am building out a template, is it possible to merge each 2 cells with no values in them as of yet

Comment: You can try it and then after the program runs enter data in the relevant cells to see if they merge.

Comment: If there is no data change ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row to what ever number of rows you need.